# I am connecting to MySQL through Java but its not getting it correct. can anyone help me?

Tags: java, mysql

This is the Exception I get:

```
[root@abc Ticket]# javac innsert.java
[root@abc Ticket]# java innsert
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)    
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)    
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)    
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)    
at innsert.main(innsert.java:13)
```

Comment: Have you added required jar ? & show us your code

Comment: Try using any good IDE, if you are not using command line version OS

Comment: i am using fedora 20

Comment: command line version?

Answer (score 0):

Add class path for the JDBC in jar in system properties. because, you are trying to Run program from command prompt.

Comment: hie @Palak ! can you tell me how to add class path for JDBC in jar system properties ! because i don't know how to do that ! Even links will help ! Thanks a lot in advance .